# UI only partly responsive while running tasks and updating ui

Tags: c#, user-interface, task

i have the following ui -

[image]

For each line connection to crm should be tested. This is done in separate thread.

The test status of the connection to crm system is then updated in last column.

The problem is that the ui is only partly reponsive during threads run and updating of the ui, i.e.
i would like to click through the lines whilst updating.

Here is my code:

```
private async void btnTestAllConnections_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await TestConnectionsAsync();
        }

        private async Task TestConnectionsAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                int idxConn = columnLookup[ColumnIndex.Connection].Index;

                if (lvInitParameters.Items.Count == 0)
                    return;

                ManagedConnection connection = null;

                btnTestAllConnections.Visible = false;
                btnTestConnection.Visible = false;
                panel2.Enabled = false;
                panel3.Enabled = false;
                tableLayoutPanel1.Enabled = false;
                btnCancelTest.Visible = true;

                List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

                var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                CancellationToken token = cts.Token;

                foreach (ListViewItem lvi in lvInitParameters.Items)
                {
                    InitParamProxy currentProfile = (InitParamProxy)lvi.Tag;

                    lvi.SubItems[idxConn].Text = "Testing...";

                    Task<bool> result =null;

                    try
                    {

                        result = Task.Run(
                  () =>
                 {
                     try
                     {
                         connection = currentProfile.ManagedConnection;
                         return connection?.ConnectionSuccess ?? false;
                     }
                     catch (Exception ex)
                     {
                         // crm exception
                         return false;
                     }
                 }, token);
                        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("\nCancellation requested in continuation...\n");
                            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                        }


                        ListViewItem testItem =
                        items.Where(si => ((InitParamProxy)lvi.Tag).ProfileKey.Equals(((InitParamProxy)si.Tag).ProfileKey)).SingleOrDefault();


                        lvi.SubItems[idxConn].Text = (result.Result) ? "Success" : "Fail";

                        if (testItem != null)
                            testItem.SubItems[idxConn].Text = (result.Result) ? "Success" : "Fail";
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        ListViewItem testItem =
                            items.Where(si => ((InitParamProxy)lvi.Tag).ProfileKey.Equals(((InitParamProxy)si.Tag).ProfileKey)).SingleOrDefault();

                        lvi.SubItems[idxConn].Text = "Canceled";

                        if (testItem != null)
                            testItem.SubItems[idxConn].Text = "Canceled";
                    }

                    tasks.Add(result);
                }

                Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

                btnTestAllConnections.Visible = true;
                btnTestConnection.Visible = true;
                panel2.Enabled = true;
                panel3.Enabled = true;
                tableLayoutPanel1.Enabled = true;
                btnCancelTest.Visible = false;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

In the end of your method you have

```
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

This will *block* until all tasks are done. You should instead use [WhenAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=net-6.0#system-threading-tasks-task-whenall(system-threading-tasks-task()))

```
await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

You are also using `result.Result` in several places, and this also blocks. This should be replaced by awaiting the task, i.e. `await result`

Comment: thx Jonas, but ui still freezes ...

Comment: @user17582358 I have amended the answer

Comment: @user17582358 you can pause the code execution if run from IDE, then evaluate where your threads are at. That could give a clue which part of UI code is still the issue.

Comment: Stepping through the code everything is ok (values of listview items, threads ended correctly), but ui just flickers and does not refresh. Clicking on ui makes it inresponsive for a while...

Comment: @user17582358 The UI will only be updated after the code that updates the UI is run. If you are using winforms you might need to insert [invalidate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) call(s) to force a redraw. In general I would recommend using a performance profiler, that should show you when the UI is blocked and why.